# Rejecting specific regular expression patterns

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to regex and trying to match a string that

- can have any length
- can be alphanumeric and also can contain `$`, `-`, or `/`
- cannot contain more than two of these non-alphanumeric characters in a row or end with `/` or `-`.

For example, `Hello/World` is valid, `Hello//World` is invalid.

I've tried a couple different possibilities, with this one coming the closest to working as I'm expecting:

```
^--|-/|/-|\s\s|$$|$-|-$|$/|/$|//|([a-zA-Z0-9 -$/])*(?<![/-])$
```

This seems to be sufficient for every scenario except when two forward slashes are together.  Do the forward slashes need to be escaped, or is it because my matching expression is too broad and swallowing bad strings?  I've tried various other expressions with negative look-ahead and look-behind but they all run into issues, especially with false negatives.

Cheers,

Jeff

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Forward slashes do not need to be escaped except when using a slash as a delimiter when use of such is applicable and in that case just change the delimiter or use /{2}.  My approach would be to develop a regex to match each pattern to exclude, then or them together and put a ! in front of it so you get a match only when none of the exclusion patterns match. This would have the form !(r1|r2|...|rn) where r1,r2.. rn are the regexes of the patterns to exclude.

Comment: Using Java, but I've been trying to figure my way through using RegexPlanet.  I'll try your suggestion Tris and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex you are looking for:

```
^(?![^/$-]*[/$-]{2})[\w/$-]+(?<![/-])$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG7bW4/1) and [IDEONE Java Demo](http://ideone.com/GFUse9)

```
String str1 = "Hello/World";
String str2 = "Hello//World";
String ptrn = "^(?![^/$-]*[/$-]{2})[\\w/$-]+(?<![/-])$";
System.out.println(str1.matches(ptrn)); // => true
System.out.println(str2.matches(ptrn)); // => false
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string (unnecessary in `matches()`)
- `(?![^/$-]*[/$-]{2})` - Lookahead ensuring that the string has no more than 1 non-alphanumeric character
- `[\w/$-]+` - Main character class matching alphanumeric characters and `/`, `$` or `-`
- `(?<![/-])` - A lookbehind making sure the string does not end with the forbidden non-alphanumeric characters
- `$` - End of string (unnecessary in `matches()`)

Comment: Very interesting question I should say! Most of such conditions are usually possible with [look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and I am using both look-ahead and look-behind to set the restrictions you define.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right path with negative lookaheads, you just needed to include a capture group reference.

`^([^\$-\/]|([\$-\/])(?!\2))+?[^\/-]$`

This regex does a negative lookahead for any $, -, or / it captures. It also has a lazy quantifier to make sure it doesn't override the check for an ending / or -.